# How to implement JPA transaction with Spring Boot application?

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-boot, transactions

How to insert below object in a single transaction with spring Boot application. if anyone below object fail to insert that transaction roll back.

```
clientInBoundFilesService.saveClientInBoundFiles(clientInBoundFiles);
icdCodeService.saveICDCode(icdCode);
cptCodeService.saveCPTCode(cptCode);
insuranceService.saveInsurance(insurance);
referingProviderService.saveReferingProvider(referingProvider);
```

Here is my pom.xml

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <start-class>org.sam.application.Application</start-class>
        <java.version>1.6</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.10</version>
        </dependency>
```

Here is my JpaRepositoryFactory.java .

```
@Component
public class JpaRepositoryFactory {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public <T> T getRepository(Class clazz) {
        notNull(clazz);
        notNull(entityManager);
        T crudRepository = (T) new SimpleJpaRepository(clazz, entityManager);
        return crudRepository;
    }
}
```

Here is my Service class

```
@Service
public class ClaimDetailService {

    private JpaRepositoryFactory jpaRepositoryFactory;
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public ClaimDetailService(JpaRepositoryFactory jpaRepositoryFactory) {
        this.jpaRepositoryFactory = jpaRepositoryFactory;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.namedParameterJdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void saveClaimDetail(ClaimDetail claimDetail) {
        JpaRepository<ClaimDetail, Long> mailAuditLogLongJpaRepository = jpaRepositoryFactory.getRepository(ClaimDetail.class);
        mailAuditLogLongJpaRepository.save(claimDetail);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
clientInBoundFilesService.saveClientInBoundFiles(clientInBoundFiles);
icdCodeService.saveICDCode(icdCode);
cptCodeService.saveCPTCode(cptCode);
insuranceService.saveInsurance(insurance);
referingProviderService.saveReferingProvider(referingProvider);
```

Wrap your code with some method eq. (you can create a new service and inject needed services)

```
@Transactional
void allInOneTransaction(){
     clientInBoundFilesService.saveClientInBoundFiles(clientInBoundFiles);
     icdCodeService.saveICDCode(icdCode);
     cptCodeService.saveCPTCode(cptCode);
     insuranceService.saveInsurance(insurance);
     referingProviderService.saveReferingProvider(referingProvider);
}
```

Default @Transactional propagation is Propagation.REQUIRED ->
Support a current transaction, create a new one if none exists.